# Загружать картинки из директории, не зная имени картинки

Tags: java, android, listview, изображения, файловая-система

Есть картинки в папке, нужно их вытащить и вставить в listView, все хорошо когда жестко указываю имя картинки, а если файл переименуется... Как сделать так, чтобы можно было их загружать не зная имени файла? И возможно ли такое?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Собсна, Вам просто необходимо сделать функцию, которая бы возвращала просто список имен файлов  из папки. Получив их, вы уже сможете обращаться явными путями в Вашем списке. К примеру таким образом:

```
private ArrayList<String> getImagesName() {
        ArrayList<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myPictures/";
        File filePath = new File(path);
        File file[] = filePath.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
            fileNames.add(file[i].getName());
        }

        return fileNames;
    }
```

Как получите список имен - то загоняйте его в свой адаптер, и грузите картинку, зная полный путь до неё.

Answer (score 1):

При условии, что расширение файлов не меняется и заранее известно можно так:

1. Пробегаемся циклом по всем файлам в целевой папке.
2. Выясняем расширение файла
3. Сравниваем его со списком допустимых
4. Если подходит - устанавливаем изображение.